# C++ Specify /EHsc

Tags: c++

I am trying to use pycdc to decompile a PY exe. I have got so far, but I have no idea how to actually specific /EHsc. This is the only issue, if I fix this then all is good. But it tells me to specify /EHsc and I don't know how to do that

Error:
[error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rNZz.png)
[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXtna.png)

I try building but then I get this error.

Comment: How are you building the code? Please show a [mre] and the full error message

Comment: @AlanBirtles I am building from VS 2022 Build -> Build ALL_BUILD

Comment: Edited. I have tried everything, like adding /EHsc to commandline and nothing works

Comment: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/eh-exception-handling-model?view=msvc-170#set-the-option-in-visual-studio-or-programmatically